# CodeIgniter query to exclude a subset from results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, codeigniter-3

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to write the proper query after doing a `JOIN`.  I need to get all users in Group 1 while excluding a subset of these results.

Table `users`:

```
id    name
1     John Smith
2     Joe Blow
3     Mary Jane
```

Table `users_groups`:

```
user_id   group_id
1         1
1         3
1         4
2         1
2         4
2         5
3         1
3         6
```

Everyone in Group 6 will also be in Group 1, however, not everyone in Group 1 will be in Group 6.  In other words, Group 6 is a sub-set of Group 1.

I need a query that will give me a list of all users who are in Group 1 (while excluding the users in Group 6).  For the example above, I should get two results, `John Smith` and `Joe Blow`.

I'm using CodeIgniter v3

Here is my attempt (I removed the cache code for clarity)...

```
$this->db->from('users');

$this->db->select('
    users.id                AS `id`,
    users.name              AS `name`,
    users_groups.group_id   AS `group_id`
', FALSE);

$this->db->join('users_groups', 'users_groups.user_id = users.id', 'LEFT');

$this->db->group_by('users.email'); // remove duplication caused by JOIN

$this->db->where('users_groups.group_id = 1'); // get all users in Group 1

$this->db->where('users_groups.group_id <> 6'); // ignore all users in Group 6

return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

The problem I'm having here is that I always get the full list of users in Group 1.  Because the `JOIN` produces a list of all users and all groups, where the same user is listed multiple times, one entry for every Group that person belongs.  My query is removing the Group 6 entries, but this is no good since the same users are also in Group 1.

I just explained why my query is failing, but I still cannot figure out how to achieve success.  How do I get the Group 1 users and then remove the subset of users that are in Groups 1 & 6?  These users can also be in other Groups, but these should be ignored... I just want to exclude users who are in Groups 1 & 6 from the list of users in Group 1.

Each user in the result:

- must be in Group 1
- must not be in Group 6
- may or may not be in any other Group

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "not exists" clause in there as a filter.

```
And not exists (select 1 from users_groups x where 
x.user_id = users_groups.user_id and group_id = 6
```

Im not familiar with code ignite but im sure this is doable

Comment: It works.  The reader can refer to my answer for how to do it in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Philip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30928202/594235), it's working.  This is how to do it within CodeIgniter...

```
$this->db->where('users_groups.group_id = 1'); // get all users in Group 1

$this->db->where('
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM users_groups x 
        WHERE x.user_id = users_groups.user_id AND group_id = 6
    )
');  // exclude users in Group 6
```